# rpmbuild %clean phase without removing files

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I am getting the following in my build log:

```
Executing(%clean): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.CgE2Qn
+ umask 022
+ cd /export/home/svn_checkouts/*snip*/Output/release/bin/packaging/BUILD
+ /bin/rm -rf /export/home/svn_checkouts/*snip*/Output/release/bin
+ exit 0
```

I'd like to avoid `rpmbuild` deleting all the files in my build directory as I need them for other things after the RPM is built. Can I override this behavior?

I read that some versions of RPM support a `--noclean` argument, but ours doesn't unfortunately.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to provide my own `%clean` directive in the spec file and leave it blank to override the default. For some reason I didn't expect that to work. ;)

A define can conditionalize the *%Clean%* phase so that the same effect as `--noclean` can be achieved.

```
%Clean
%if "%{noclean}" == ""
   rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
%endif
```

Called with `rpmbuild --define 'noclean 1'` to disable cleaning.

Comment: Alas, this doesn't work with RPM version 4.11.1 : if noclean is undefined,  %{noclean} gets expanded to % { n o c l e a n }  (without the spaces) rather than an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

For **building from `spec`-file**, `rpmbuild` has the `-bi` option. It leaves the `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` as is; it does no `%clean`.

> ```
>   -bi     build through %install (%prep, %build, then install) from <specfile>
> ```

(`rpmbuild --help`)

---

For **building from `SRPM`** (a source RPM package; `yumdownloader` will get you those), there is also `--recompile` option:

> ```
>  --rebuild    build binary package from <source package>
>  --recompile  build through %install (%prep, %build, then install) from <source package>
> ```

---

Finally, there is `--noclean` option for `rpmbuild` — but in my case (`RPM version 4.11.3`) it didn't work.